# On the definition of Hirsch length

Tags: group-theory

I found definition of the Hirsch length in two books for two classes of groups:

J.A. Hillman defined it for elementary amenable groups in his book "The Algebraic Characterization of Geometric 4-Manifolds" as following:

The Hirsch number of $h(G)$ of an elementary amenable group is a nonnegative integer or $\infty$, defined as follows: if $G$ is in $X_1$ let $h(G)$ be the rank of an abelian subgroup of finite index in $G$. If $h(G)$ has been defined for all $G$ in $X_{\alpha}$ and $H$ is in $l X_{\alpha}$ let $$h(H)=l.u.b.\{ h(F)|F\leq H,\; F\in X_{\alpha}\}.$$ Finally, if $G$ is in $X_{\alpha +1}$, so has a normal subgroup $H$ in $lX_{\alpha}$ with $G/H$ in $X_1$, let $h(G)=h(H)+h(G/H)$. For definitions of $X_1$ and $X_{\alpha}$, please see the book "Algebraic Characterization of Geometric 4-Manifolds" p. 3. See also Section 1.5 of Hillman's later monograph *Four-manifolds, geometries and knots* ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212142)).

On the other hand J.S. Robinson  defined it for polycyclic groups in his book "A course in the theory of groups" as follows:

In a polycyclic group $G$ the number of infinite factors in a cyclic series
is independent of the series and hence is an invariant of $G$ (known as the
Hirsch length).

Now I have two questions:

(1) Can we define the Hirsch length for all groups generally?

(2)  What is relationship between elementary amenable groups and polycyclic groups? I mean is every polycyclic group an elementary amenable group or conversely?

Comment: Can you maybe clarify the general definition of Hirsch length? Is $h(g)=n<\infty$ if $G$ has a series $1 = G_0 \rhd G_1 \rhd \cdots \rhd G_r = G$ in
which the factors are either locally finite or infinite cyclic, and exactly $n$ factors are infinite cyclic, and $h(G) = \infty$ otherwise?

Comment: @user1729 This is my question. Sorry, I asked my question badly and I've just edited it. Is this the definition of Hirsch number for an arbitrary goup?

Comment: It is the definition for an amenable group which I found in a paper, but I do not know if it matches the definition of Hillman. Your question is impossible to answer without knowing Hillman's definition...

Comment: *Please provide **context!*** You have been told this multiple times!  Also, please ask one question at a time and please do not rely on pictures of text

Comment: @user1729 I've added the definition of Hillman in my question. Could you please tell me what the relationship between amenable groups and polycyclic by finite groups is? Is every polycyclic by finite group an amenable group or vice versa?

Comment: @Shaun Sure. Consider it done.

Comment: I really liked your "I have two questions:..." list structure - it was much clearer than the current version :-) Also, it would be better if you typed up Hillman's definition rather than using a screenshot, so people with screen readers could see it.

Comment: @user1729 Sure. I'll do it. This is because I am really afraid of Shaun's comments. Everytime I ask a question, he appears and tells something to me. I know he is right but I forget sometimes to write details.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks very much for the comments and your help. I'll try to edit my question again and write them as you told.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hirsch length is classically defined for polycyclic groups. The extension to amenable groups is more recent.

Polycyclic groups are amenable. To see this, note that the class of amenable groups is closed under extensions, that is if $N$ and $H/N$ are both amenable then $H$ is amenable. So to prove polycyclic groups are amenable, proceed by induction on the Hirsch length of your polycyclic group $G$.

Here is an image ("Bridson's Universe", but with a Monster inset) which may help you visualise the world of groups. PC here is polycyclic. More details, including a key, are [here](https://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/bridsons-universe-of-finitely-presented-groups/).

[image: Bridson's Universe]

---

Anyway, on to your specific question about Hirsch length for arbitrary groups. Bridson and Kropholler prove that Hillman's definition is equivalent to the following (see Section I.13 of their paper *Dimension of elementary amenable groups*,  Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik (Crelles Journal) 2015 ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1084)):

- $h(G)=n<\infty$ if $G$ has a series $$1=G_0\rhd G_1\rhd\cdots\rhd G_r=G$$ in which the factors are either locally finite or infinite cyclic, and exactly $n$ factors are infinite cyclic, and
- $h(G)=\infty$ otherwise.

This definition clearly extends to arbitrary groups. *However*, if $h(G)$ is finite then $G$ is amenable (why?). Therefore, it is not a useful definition for non-amenable groups!

---

We could try and conjure up a definition which works more widely. However, the definition would need to be quite different from the standard subnormal series definition. The game then becomes finding a definition which

(a) has some properties of Hirsch length (e.g. if $G$ surjects onto $H$ then $h(G)\geq h(H)$), and

(b) which matches the existing definitions for amenable groups.

For example, for torsion-free polycyclic groups, cohomological dimension matches Hirsch length, $cd(G)=h(G)$, but cohomological dimension does not respect homomorphic images, e.g. the free group $F_2$ surjects onto your favourite non-free group $H$ and $cd(F_2)=0\leq cd(H)$.

Comment: I really appreciate your nice answer. I understood completely. Thank you very much for your help.